# How to exit a shell script if one part of it fails?

Tags: bash, scripting, error-handling

How can I write a shell script that exits, if  one part of it fails?
For example, if the following code snippet fails, then the script should exit.

```
n=0
until [ $n -ge 5 ]
do
  gksu *command* && break
  n=$[$n+1]
  sleep 3
```

Answer (score 150):

One approach would be to add `set -e` to the beginning of your script. That means (from `help set`):

```
  -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
```

So if any of your commands fail, the script will exit.

Alternatively, you can add explicit `exit` statements at the possible failure points:

```
command || exit 1
```

Comment: I (and [the bash wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)) would rather people put some thought in proper error handling rather than using the (broken by design IMO) `set -e` feature. It doesn't really apply here though. The OP wants to exit the script after 5 failing attempts to run the command.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I won't argue with you about whether it's broken, I'm sure you're right. However, the OP asked "How can I write a shell script that exits, if one part of it fails?", what makes you think it's about exiting after 5 failures?

Comment: because I can't think of any other way the question can be interpreted.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas you may well be right. I interpreted it literally: how can the whole script exit if any part of it fails. And `set -e` is the only way I know to do that.

Comment: In that script snipet, the commands that could trigger `set -e` is `sleep` (`break` being a special builtin would cause the script to exit on failure in most shells, commands in `if` or to the left of `&&` are not affected by `set -e`, `n=...` could fail if `n` is read-only, but then that would exit the script without `set -e` as well), so that interpretation sounds quite unlikely. I agree the question is poorly worded.

Comment: Wouldn't failure of either `gksu` or `command` also trigger it? That's what I was thinking of.

Comment: No, as that's on the left part of `&&` so used as a condition.

Answer (score 25):

You can exit a script at any place using the keyword `exit`. You can also specify an exit code in order to indicate to other programs that or how your script failed, e.g. `exit 1` or `exit 2` etc. (By convention, exit code 0 is for success and anything greater than 0 signifies failure; however, also by convention, exit codes above 127 are reserved for abnormal termination (e.g. by a signal)).

The generic construction to exit on failure is

```
if [ failure condition ]; then
    exit n
fi
```

with suitable `failure condition` and `n`. But in specific scenarios you may proceed differently. Now for your case I interpret your question that if any of the five invocations of `gksu` fail, then you mean to exit. One way is to use a function like this

```
function try_command {
    for i in 1 2 3 4 5 ; do
        if gksu command ; then
            return 0
        fi
    fi
    exit 1
}
```

and then, invoke the loop by `try_command`.

There are (more) advanced or sophisticated ways of how to address your question. However, the solution above is more accessible to beginners than, say, Stephane's solution.

Answer (score 15):

```
attempt=0
until gksu command; do
  attempt=$((attempt + 1))
  if [ "$attempt" -gt 5 ]; then
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

`exit` exits the script unless it's called in a subshell. If that part of the script is in a subshell, for instance because it's within `(...)` or `$(...)` or part of a pipe-line, then it will only exit *that subshell*.

In that case, if you want the *script* to exit in addition to the subshell, then you'll need to call `exit` upon that subshell exiting.

For instance, here with 2 nested levels of subshells:

```
(
  life=hard
  output=$(
    echo blah
    [ "$life" = easy ] || exit 1 # exit subshell
    echo blih not run
  ) || exit # if the subshell exits with a non-zero exit status,
            # exit as well with the same exit status

  echo not run either
) || exit # if the subshell exits with a non-zero exit status,
          # exit as well with the same exit status
```

It can become trickier if the subshell is part of a pipeline. `bash` has a special `$PIPESTATUS` array, similar to `zsh`'s `$pipestatus` one that can help you here:

```
{
   echo foo
   exit 1
   echo bar
} | wc -c
subshell_ret=${PIPESTATUS[0]}
if [ "$subshell_ret" -ne 0 ]; then
  exit "$subshell_ret"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Trap will perform an action upon receiving a signal.

```
trap "echo EXIT;  exit" 0
trap "echo HUP;   exit" 1
trap "echo CTL-C; exit" 2
trap "echo QUIT;  exit" 3
trap "echo ERR;   exit" ERR
n=0
until [ $n -ge 5 ]
do
  n=$[$n+1]
  echo $n
  sleep 3
done
```

Run this and let it exit normally. It traps on signal 0.

```
EXIT
```

Run it again and interrupt with ^C.  It traps on both signal 2 and signal 0.

```
CTL-C
EXIT
```

A non-zero exit status will trap on ERR

```
ERR
EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pass_to_functio()
{
  echo "command exited with status $1"
}

(
 exec <Any Command >  &
 child_pid=$!
 wait $child_pid
 pass_to_function $?
)&
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer doing it this way:

- explicit exit at important commands
- common function for notification about failure, to not miss it

```
function exit_failed() {
    echo ""
    echo "  ... batch failed !!!"
    echo ""

    exit 1
}

7z a $FN . || exit_failed
<call-something-else> || exit_failed
```