# How to add set -e to all default bashes?

Tags: bash, error-handling

To make [a bash script exit after any failed command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309339/how-to-exit-a-shell-script-if-one-part-of-it-fails), you can add

```
set -e
```

Imagine, you have a CI agent which allow people to embed bash scripts as tasks in build jobs.

How to make the exit behaviour given by `set -e` default for all new bash instances? Is there some sort of `bashrc` hack for that?

Comment: Putting `SHELLOPTS=errexit` in the environment would do it, but in my opinion [and that of many `set -e` is almost never the right way to do error handling](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the present running bash shell activate the `-e` option with:

```
$ set -e
```

Just to confirm:

```
$ echo "$-"
himBHs
$ set -e
ehimBHs
```

As the bashrc file is sourced to interactive shells you can make all **new** bash shells use the `-e` option by adding this:

```
set -e
```

As one line at any place (that is executed) of the `.bashrc` script.

This is a **very bad idea** however, as there are many conditions under which the detection of a failed command fails and there are several cases where a failed command is desirable. [Please read](https://serverfault.com/a/416097)